# Captcha not showing input....

Tags: support, captcha

When prompted for a Captcha by SU, There's no visible captcha text and no input box. The only thing visible is the "I'm a human" button.

Windows XP, FireFox 4

Form Source:

```
        <form method="post" action="/captcha?s=47e22f3a-3f5c-4c8c-8df9-c9b24b7b19e5">                
            <div><script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
            theme : 'clean',
            tabindex : 0
        };

</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LcDNwYAAAAAAG_X1rC8kTtLBP6XS2Ym1N0n9kSY">

</script><noscript>
        <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LcDNwYAAAAAAG_X1rC8kTtLBP6XS2Ym1N0n9kSY" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0">

        </iframe><br>

        </br><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" type="hidden" />
</noscript></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() { $("#recaptcha_response_field").focus(); });
            </script>
            <noscript>
                You must enter the confirmation code in the box above after solving the challenge
            </noscript>

            <p>
            </p>
            <input id="btn-captcha" style="font-weight: bold;" type="submit" name="post" value="&nbsp;I'm a Human Being&nbsp;" /><br>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specific problem and fix found:

HTTPS-Everywhere forces the use of the secure reCAPTCHA API. The problem with this is the invalid certificate used; specifically, it is expired as of 09-05-04 13:32:04 (GMT).

This can be worked around by navigating to https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/ and adding a permanent exception for the certificate.

Tested on Firefox 4 final on Ubuntu 10.10 to https://superuser.com/captcha.

Comment: excellent detective work!

Comment: Agreed - Very nicely done! Thanks for your help and the workaround.

Comment: @Jeff @Hello71 I emailed Google and was pointed at this announcement: http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha-announce/browse_thread/thread/c1ff6844420c9e63?pli=1

Comment: This won't help: the expired certificate was installed by Google on purpose, as SSL support for that domain [is due to end soon](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/57baacc2a067035a/8e88d1199244a778?tvc=2), like @Basiclife already heard from Google. See also [Captcha failed to display](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89494/captcha-failed-to-display) on MSO.

Comment: @Arjan: It'll do for now. Alternatively, download [the fixed development version](https://github.com/Hello71/HTTPS-Everywhere/) or apply [this patch](https://github.com/Hello71/HTTPS-Everywhere/commit/3a280686a9720d31040ae95ea25f0d25b552585c) to the "official" svn development version.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this. In Firefox 4

https://superuser.com/captcha

Shows up just fine for me .. can you try in Firefox safe mode, or check to see if a firewall or proxy is interfering with recaptcha showing?

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'll try it now and get back to you.

Comment: Confirmed: In safe mode, captcha shows fine. I'm disabling add-ons one by one to see what triggers it. Will be back to you shortly. This is odd as I use SO frequently and never have issues with this...

Comment: Further to the above, the issue seems to be cause by [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). This also occurs on SO (and I assume other SE sites). I've had the addon installed for a considerable length of time (months) and haven't had issues before - not sure if it's recently been updated or if something about recaptcha has changed - In any case, my issue is diagnosed and I'll do without the addon for now. (I can accept your answer if you'd like this closed?)

Comment: Specifically, it's Google APIs that causes the problem.